# Auto update app desktop python with Pyqt5 and AWS RDS

Tags: python, auto-update

I want to launch a desktop application to run customer records for my sister at work,

- We are actually using local storage with sqlite3, but I will switch to AWS RDS sql

The application uses these packages:

```
from PyQt5 import uic,QtWidgets 
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import sqlite3, csv
```

Our biggest problem is the update in the application that for each new functionality needs a new installation,

The packages I want to send in the update can contain .ui files,

I try unsuccessfully to use:

-Updater4pyi
-PyUpdater
-Esky

Esky seemingly out of phase and do not support some configurations and I believe that the tools doesn't work correctly freezing the app to .exe because de .ui files,

What is the possible solution to this issue?

Thank you in advance

Setup.py

```
import esky.bdist_esky
from esky.bdist_esky import Executable as Executable_Esky
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
include_files = ['consulta2.ui']
setup(
    name = 'cadastro',
    version = '1.0',
    options = {
        'build_exe': {
            'packages': ['sqlite3','csv'],
            'excludes': ['tkinter','tcl','ttk'],
            'include_files': include_files,
            'include_msvcr': True,
        },
        'bdist_esky': {
            'freezer_module': 'cx_freeze',
        }
    },
    data_files = include_files,
    scripts = [
        Executable_Esky(
            "controle.py",
            gui_only = False,
            #icon = XPTO #Coloque um icone aqui se quiser ,
            ),
    ],
    executables = [Executable('controle.py',base='Win32GUI')]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to execute continuos deploy,

With new functions and screens

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please only post an answer if it's *an answer*. If you want to mention something like this, just add it to your question by editing or commenting.